# gearman issues & php cli

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, gearman

I'm having some gearman issues when trying to run commands in terminal using php cli. For example I run this command:

`gearmand --log-file=/var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log`

and get:

`gearmand: Could not open log file "/usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log", from "/home/jeitnier", switching to stderr. (No such file or directory)`

`ERROR 2013-01-25 16:25:53.000000 [  main ] bind(Address already in use) -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:612`

`ERROR 2013-01-25 16:25:53.000000 [  main ] bind(Transport endpoint is not connected) -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:626`

The first line brings up my first issue which after Googling for hours, gives me nothing...Why is there an issue writing to the log? I can't seem to fix this. This occurs after running any commands.

Does anyone know what these errors are? Is it time to remove and re-install all gearman related items?

Comment: Where are you using php-cli?

Comment: 1. does `/usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log` exists? 2. you have something already listening on the gearmand port (possibly already running?)

Comment: mac terminal with sudo access

Comment: @Prisoner, well no but that's what I'm trying to figure out. How'd it come up with this path to begin with and how do I get it correct?

Comment: It came up with this path because you defined that path when starting gearmand. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following from the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/gearman-job-server/
sudo touch /var/log/gearman-job-server/gearmand.log
sudo killall gearmand
sudo gearmand --log-file=/var/log/gearman-job-server/gearmand.log
```

Comment: ran the process like 3 minutes ago and it's still running/waiting, is this normal?

Comment: that means it's running. if you open up another terminal tab and run `tail -f /var/log/gearman-job-server/gearmand.log` it should tell you it's started. If you want to run geramand in the background (without having to keep the terminal window open, run: `sudo gearmand --log-file=/var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: I just noticed there was a gearman.log but not gearmand.log, guess I should watch out for ALL characters next time. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: The line to set the log-file location doesn't seem to be working. I created the new path/file but it's still looking for `usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log`

Comment: according to http://gearman.org/manual:job_server `--log-file` is the correct switch. Type `man gearmand` and make sure `--log-file` is correct. You could try just using `-l` instead, but it probably wont make a single difference.

Comment: I mean, I run the process but it just sits there.

Comment: Even if you run this: `sudo gearmand --log-file=/var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log > /dev/null 2>&1 &`?

Comment: Gives me `Done` but then `sudo gearmand -d` gives me the same wrong log path message

Comment: Ah, didn't see the `-d` switch. Run `sudo gearmand -d --log-file=/var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log`

Comment: An other way is to change access permission : chmod o=+rw /var/log/gearman-job-server/gearmand.log