# gearmand: Could not open log file "/usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log"

Tags: worker, gearman

I'm trying to install gearman in my Ubuntu 12.04.
Actually installation is successful. But when I start the daemon, I'm getting this error.
*gearmand: Could not open log file "/usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log" from xxxx switching to stderr. (No such file or directory)*

Am I missing anything here? I tried installing various versions of gearman, still the result is same.
Any help please...

Comment: maybe this helps....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526086/gearman-issues-php-cli

Comment: It's probably a permissions issue.  Did you try running it with sudo?

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log` is default value of `--log-file` option.

See `gearmand --help`

```
  -l [ --log-file ] arg (=/usr/local/var/log/gearmand.log)
                                        Log file to write errors and 
                                        information to. If the log-file 
                                        parameter is specified as 'stderr', 
                                        then output will go to stderr. If 
                                        'none', then no logfile will be 
                                        generated.
```